# Organization size, number of managers or officials, or organizational charts for organizations (NGOs, firms, etc)

Tags: network-structure

I'm interested in the size of organizations (ANY organizations), the number of managers and/or officials, salary/compensation, operating territories, and the organizational structure of the organization. For organizational structure, I mean something that could be represented as a network. This includes current and past data.

This data would generally be useful for researchers in the social sciences (that's me), so I'm keeping this question pretty broad. Are there open data databases or datasets for this anywhere? Are there sources which are not quite databases but which could be easily programmatically scraped to build a dataset?

### Public and Regulated Companies (US)

The US Securities and Exchange Comission (SEC)'s online database, EDGAR, might contain some usable information, but I was unable to find anything obvious.

### Governments (US)

I did find that a web search would bring up org charts for some US national departments, agencies, and so on, and some US states. Everything I have found would need a lot of human work to put into a usable data format, even with the assistance of some PDF or web scraping.

### International (outside the US)

I looked at Canada's Innovation, Science and Economic Development (ISED) and Germany's BaFin, but they seemed to have no useful information.

### Private Databases

I found a paper from the 80s where the researcher obtained data from Hewitt (which is now Aon Solutions). I suspect there are a number of large consulting firms (e.g. Deloitte) and also firms that sell title and pay information (e.g. Payscale, Glassdoor) that could have this information, or at least some of it.